# Suming column and dividing by distinct items from another field

Tags: sql, distinct, division

I need to sum one column and divide by the distinct values in another column

```
Column A           Column B
10                  James
20                  Phill
02                  James
10                  Bill
23                  Bill
14                  James
```

My answer needs to be sum of column A (79) divided by the distinct James (3), PHILL (1), BILL (2)

My answers should be:

```
James  26.333
Phil   79
Bill   39.5
```

I tried:

```
select sum(column A)/distinct (column B)
```

Comment: What is your SQL Flavor (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Sum the amount column and group by the names.

SELECT Name, SUM(Amount) As Amt FROM TableName GROUP BY Name

My result:

```
Name    Amt
Bill    33
James   26
Phill   20
```

Your question changed. I will update answer...

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM TableName) / COUNT(Name) AS CalcAmount, Name
FROM TableName GROUP BY Name
```

Result:

```
CalcAmount  Name
39  Bill
26  James
79  Phill
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.sum_number/ count(t2.name), t2.name
from (
  select sum(number) as sum_number
  from t) as t1
join t as t2
join t as t3
  on t2.name = t3.name
  and t2.number = t3.number
group by t2.name
```

You can fiddle with it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25aedf/14)

Comment: Unnecessary complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with window functions:

```
select columnB,
       sum(sum(columnA)) over ()) / count(columnB) as YourAverage
from t
group by columnB;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4ef5b/4) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: This will not run as aggregates are calculated **before** window functions, you need to nest it in a Derived Table/CTE

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
SELECT C2, MAX(A.SUMC1)/COUNT(C2) CalcAmount
FROM TableA,
(SELECT SUM(C1) SUMC1 FROM TableA) A
GROUP BY C2
```

It worked , i Checked in SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54794/6/0

Comment: This does not give the OP desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,
assuming that : 
table name = test, Column A = sales, Column B = Name

```
     SELECT a.name, 
     (SELECT SUM(b.sales) / COUNT(a.NAME) FROM test AS b)
     FROM test AS a
     GROUP BY NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

When your DBMS supports "window functions" you might do:

```
SELECT ColB, CAST(SUM(SumA) OVER () AS FLOAT)/cnt CalcAmount
FROM
 (
   SELECT
      ColB,
      SUM(ColA) AS SumA, 
      COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM TableA
   GROUP BY ColB
 ) AS dt
```

If ColA is an INTEGER you need to CAST(SUM(SumA) OVER () AS FLOAT/DECIMAL) to avoid atruncation of the result